# Series$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} x^n $ converges each $x\in[-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the Series

> $\displaystyle\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} x^n $ converges each $x\in[-1,1]$

Solution i tried -In the given question if i suppose $x=1$ then the series will be $\displaystyle\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} 1 $ ,which is not convergent ,but answer in my book is it is convergent ,how ?

Please help

Comment: i am suffering a lot because of this book ,every answer is wrong,

Comment: *Which* book is that?

Comment: I am using "Arihant book" for previous GATE(Mathematics national level  exam in India) questions solutions,This book is nightmare for me now, I know answers of most of time but because of this book i have to post it here.

Comment: Are you sure it does not ask about $x\in(1,-1)$?

Comment: still this is book's fault ,i am tired of this book.

Comment: @almagest in book this is [-1,1]

Comment: If that kind of thing is happening repeatedly, use a different book!

Comment: @almagest  i checked it online on GATE papers and yes you are right this is (-1,1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is wrong. A series $\sum a_n$ cannot converge unless $a_n \to 0$. Hence the given series does not converge for $x=1$ and $x=-1$.